# Google Tag Manager causes full page reload in SPA - React

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

When I add trigger in GTM on a React `<a />` or `<Link />` element it causes full page reload on click instead of re-rendering just part of application.

When I remove google tracking, everything works smoothly. Is there a way, how to configure GTM to not affect behaviour of application?

Comment: Just to be sure, the behavior is caused by the trigger itself, not the tag fired (since first paragraph talks about triggers, second paragraph talks about the google tracking).  Do you use a click trigger ? If so, do you have it set to "all elements" or to "only links"? If the latter, try to uncheck "wait for tags" and "wait for tags" checkboxes respectively. If that does not help the question is probably not answerable with the information given.

Comment: I had "wait for tags" enabled and it was really the root cause. I have to check with guys who did the setup of GTM why was that necessary. Thanks @EikePierstorff

Comment: It's checked by default, so the developers simply didn't bother to uncheck it. It's not necessary on SPAs, since the users never leave the page on an SPA (the purpose if "wait for tags" is to give requests  time to finish before the link navigates the user away fro the page).

Comment: Thanks for explanation, feel free to answer this question, I'll accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 10):

If strange things happens with Google Tag Manager link click tracking the first thing you should do is to go to your click trigger setup and see if the "wait for tags" and "check validation" checkboxes are enabled (as they are by default) and uncheck them.

They are not necessary in an SPA and (as evidenced) potentially harmful; "wait for tags" adds a delay so that other tags have time to fire before a the link directs a user away from the page (which does not happen within SPAs in any case), "check validation" tests if the link target is a valid URI (which within an SPA it probably isn't by GTMs standards - for example links starting with a hash are not valid etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate function and use context router to change route ex:

```
myFunction(url) {
 this.context.router.push({ 
      pathname: url
    });
}
<Link onClick={this.myFunction.bind(this,url)} ></Link>
```

attach this function to onClick of Link tag.